# How to access external database from Node container?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, next.js

I have a `nextjs` app which is supposed to connect to an external MySQL database (not one from the same docker network). When running the app locally, it works correctly when connecting to DB, but when running it in a Docker container it keeps on trying to connect to 127.0.0.1, even though the environment variables are configured correctly in the container

```
Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
nextjs_1  |     at connect (/opt/app/node_modules/serverless-mysql/index.js:80:15)
```

Dockerfile config:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package.json /opt/app
COPY package-lock.json /opt/app

RUN npm install --no-optional

COPY . /opt/app

RUN npm run build

RUN npx next telemetry disable

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

USER nextjs

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Connection code:

```
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')

const db = mysql({
  config: {
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
  },
})

exports.query = async (query) => {
  try {
    const results = await db.query(query)
    await db.end()
    return results
  } catch (error) {
    return { error }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *"the environment variables are configured correctly in the container"* - you aren't showing that part, have you validated this?

Comment: for sure its environment variable issue, as @jonrsharpe mentioned you should validate this.

Comment: Is it possible to share the log? maybe console.log() out the variables.